# Webservice object and multipart

Tags: spring-boot, request, multipart

I want to make a webservice with to param, one **object** user and another **multipart** to recieve a file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signUpOrUpdateAvatar", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data")
    public User signUpAvatar(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders header,  @RequestPart("user")  User user,
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws LogicBusinessException {
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()); 
        //TODO call others methods
        return userRet;
    }
```

When I try gives me this error:

```
    {
  "timestamp": 1492500929835,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
  "message": "Required request part 'file' is not present",
  "path": "/signUpOrUpdateAvatar2"
}
```

[image: swagger]

Comment: Do you need the 1st parameters @RequestHeader. Can you remove and give a try

Comment: @CrazyMac same error

Comment: Then the way you are pushing the file from front end may be wrong. How are you calling this service from your front end and how is the file parameter being passed

Comment: @CrazyMac I am using swagger but for user but for user does not detec its a json I think

Comment: Are you building your multi-part request properly? Check out the Mozilla tutorial here, are you missing the boundary or something else? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Dealing_with_binary_data

Answer (score 2):

Add the below bean in your java config

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    cmr.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
    return cmr;
}
```

Comment: It helps! But don't forget to add `commons-fileupload` in your dependencies. And the `maxUploadSize` isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to get the file data via a different thread. Try using the same thread that has the @MultipartConfig full annotation, and use StandardServletMultipartResolver rather than CommonsMultipartResolver in your @Bean.

Answer (score 0):

**You need a rest API which takes two parameters from which one is a multipart object and other is some parameter. I have implemented Rest service which probably fulfills your need.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public URL uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
/***
//Your business logic
/***

}
```

Best of luck..